# How to I get JUST the row with the greatest term code

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to be able to get the row that has the greatest/biggest/largest TERM_CODE_EFF
I need to change something similar to the following query:

```
SELECT MAJR_CODE_MINR_1 AS Minor1,
       MAJR_CODE_MINR_1_2 AS Minor2,
       MAJR_CODE_MINR_2 AS Minor3,
       MAJR_CODE_MINR_2_2 AS Minor4
FROM SGBSTDN
WHERE SGBSTDN_PIDM = '367021'
```

into something like this:

```
SELECT MAX (TERM_CODE_EFF) AS TermCode,
       MAJR_CODE_MINR_1 AS Minor1,
       MAJR_CODE_MINR_1_2 AS Minor2,
       MAJR_CODE_MINR_2 AS Minor3,
       MAJR_CODE_MINR_2_2 AS Minor4
FROM SGBSTDN
WHERE SGBSTDN_PIDM = '367021'
```

This gives me an ORA-00937: not a single-group group function. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX (TERM_CODE_EFF) AS TermCode,
       MAJR_CODE_MINR_1 AS Minor1,
       MAJR_CODE_MINR_1_2 AS Minor2,
       MAJR_CODE_MINR_2 AS Minor3,
       MAJR_CODE_MINR_2_2 AS Minor4
FROM SGBSTDN
WHERE SGBSTDN_PIDM = '367021'
group by MAJR_CODE_MINR_1 ,MAJR_CODE_MINR_1_2 ,MAJR_CODE_MINR_2 ,MAJR_CODE_MINR_2_2
```

Please do some research before posting your question. There are abundant solutions available online for these types of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use `order by` and `rownum`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT TERM_CODE_EFF,
             MAJR_CODE_MINR_1 AS Minor1,
             MAJR_CODE_MINR_1_2 AS Minor2,
             MAJR_CODE_MINR_2 AS Minor3,
             MAJR_CODE_MINR_2_2 AS Minor4
      FROM SGBSTDN
      WHERE SGBSTDN_PIDM = '367021'
      ORDER BY TERM_CODE_EFF DESC
     ) t
WHERE rownum = 1;
```